# Delete node in linked list not deleting proper node

Tags: java, linked-list

I started my basis for this question here and was told to start a new thread: [Delete elements within a Linked List](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51031888/delete-elements-within-a-linked-list)

I finished my code below:

```
public class MyLinked {
    static class Node {
        public Node (double item, Node next) { this.item = item; 
this.next = next; }
        public double item;
        public Node next;
        } 
    int N;
    Node first;
public void delete (int k) {
        if (k < 0 || k >= N) throw new IllegalArgumentException ();

        if (k == 0) {
            Node temp = first;
            first = first.next;
            temp.next = null;
        }else { 
            Node previous = first;
            while (k < N -1) {
                previous = previous.next;
                k++;
            }

        Node current = previous.next;
        previous.next = current.next;
        current.next = null;
        N--;
        }
    }
```

I think i'm pointing to the proper nodes to delete the k-th element, however, here is what the test is returning:

```
[ 11 21 31 41 ].delete( 0 ): Expected 4 nodes, but got less.
[ 11 21 31 41 ].delete( 1 ): expected=[ 11 31 41 ], actual=[ 11 21 31 ]
[ 11 21 31 41 ].delete( 3 ): expected=[ 11 21 31 ], actual=[ 11 31 41 ]
[ 11 21 31 41 51 ].delete( 0 ): Expected 5 nodes, but got less.
[ 11 21 31 41 51 ].delete( 1 ): expected=[ 11 31 41 51 ], actual=[ 11 21 31 41 ]
[ 11 21 31 41 51 ].delete( 2 ): expected=[ 11 21 41 51 ], actual=[ 11 21 31 51 ]
[ 11 21 31 41 51 ].delete( 3 ): expected=[ 11 21 31 51 ], actual=[ 11 21 41 51 ]
[ 11 21 31 41 51 ].delete( 4 ): expected=[ 11 21 31 41 ], actual=[ 11 31 41 51 ]
```

I think the error is that when it's trying to delete a [0], it's deleting at [1], when [1] at [2].  I imagine it's starting at [1] instead of [0] as the first node in the list?   Any help on how to adjust my code to read properly is much appreciated.

Here is the test code:

```
 private static void testDelete (int k, String list, String expected) {
        MyLinked actual = MyLinked.of (list);
        String message = String.format ("[ %s ].delete( %d )", list, 
k);
        try {
            actual.delete (k);
        } catch (Throwable e) {
            String exception = e.getClass ().getName ();
            if (! exception.equals (expected)) {
                e.printStackTrace (); // for debugging
                showError (String.format ("%s: expected=%s, 
actual=%s", message, expected, exception));
            }
            return;
        }
        check (message, actual, expected);
    }
```

Comment: Could you provide your test code?

Comment: Sorry, updated with test code.

Comment: HINT: If `delete(k)` means delete the k'th item from the beginning, why are you counting from k up to the size of the list instead of from 0 up to k?

Comment: Where is the message about the expected number of nodes coming from?

Comment: Seems like you either initialize the list incorrect or test it incorrect, I've tried your code and it works at least for `delete(0)` and `delete(1)`

Comment: @ScottHunter there was a program shell that was given and we were to just code the top portion.  There are a few lines like this :
testDelete (0, "11 21 31 41", "[ 21 31 41 ]");
that the test runs off of.

KevinAnderson you're probably right, this is why it's not starting at 0.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Delete elements within a Linked List](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51031888/delete-elements-within-a-linked-list)

Answer (score 0):

I was able to adjust my code and got the correct answer.  The working code is below:

```
    public void delete (int k) {
        if (k < 0 || k >= N) throw new IllegalArgumentException ();

        if (k == 0) {
            Node temp = first;
            first = first.next;
            temp.next = null;
            N--;
        }
        else {  
            Node previous = first;
            int count = 0;
            while (count < k-1) {
                previous = previous.next;
                count++;
            }

        Node current = previous.next;
        previous.next = current.next;
        current.next = null;
    N--;
        }
   }
```

I added in int count and set the counter to start at 0.  When I had it starting at 1, that's why it was deleting the wrong value.

I also needed to add in N-- to the (k==0) portion of the function to resize the list if the list only contained one element, and that element was deleted.